# changing all numbers (except 0 and 1) to 0 using regular expression in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am going to change any number except 1 and 0 to 0 in a column of data frame. This is my code. But it does not work.

```
df2['AgDg'] = df2['AgDg'].replace(r'\[2-9]\d*', 0, regex=True)
```

This is a sub-set of a data frame:

```
Index   value 
1        0
2        45
3        135
4        1
5        1
```

the output should be like this 
This is a sub-set of a data frame:

```
  Index   value 
    1        0
    2        0
    3        0
    4        1
    5        1
```

Comment: Why not `df2['AgDg'].where(df2['AgDg'] == '1', '0')`? Do you have a str type column? are the numbers embedded in some other string?

Comment: Are your entries integers or strings?

Comment: @ they are integers. How can I handle it if they are combination of string and integers ?

Comment: @psidom, so your code will replace all numbers except 0 and 1 to 0 ?

Comment: The code will replace all values in the column that are not `"1"` with `"0"`; Since `"0"` is already `"0"`, so logically it's the same as what you need. If you have integers, then use numbers `df2['AgDg'].where(df2['AgDg'] == 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entries are numbers, you can `map`the values, so that `1`becomes `1` and all other values `0`. For that I have used a `lambda` (inline) function:

```
df2['AgDg'] = df2['AgDg'].map(lambda val:1 if val == 1 else 0)
```

This will turn your values to integers, whatever numbers they were. Otherwise you can also use the `where` function as in the comments:

```
df2['AgDg'] = df2['AgDg'].where(df2['AgDg'] == 1, 0)
```

`where()` picks and keeps the elements that fulfill the requirement (i.e., equal to `1` in this case. The second argument is what values to assign to elements not fulfilling the requirements (i.e., set all other elements to `0´).

In this case, when we are updating the current data frame, there it is also possible to do it 'inplace' which means that we update the current data directly, instead of assigning. Then the command becomes:

```
df2['AgDg'].where(df2['AgDg'] == 1, 0, True)
```

To make it a bit more clear, it is also possible to name the in arguments (which I would recommend, when using more than the most common arguments to improve readability):

```
df2['AgDg'].where(df2['AgDg'] == 1, other=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: @ Johanl, thanks,  I still do not understand how the second solution works. can you explain it ?

Comment: I added a bit of explanation. I hope that makes it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Let's use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) and `ne`. We are putting a mask over all non-one values:

```
df.assign(value=df.value.mask(df.value.ne(1),0))
```

or as Ted Petrou suggests

```
df.assign(value=df.value.eq(1).mul(1))
```

Output:

```
   Index  value
0      1      0
1      2      0
2      3      0
3      4      1
4      5      1
```

Comment: Or how about `df.value.eq(1).mul(1)`. Which one is faster?

Comment: @TedPetrou Yep, that is nearly twice as fast.  I like.